# Error with MAMP Pro

Tags: mysql, passwords, mamp

I've been looking around for a way to resolve this issue. When i start my MAMP Pro I receive this error

> **/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user ‘root’@'localhost’ (using password: NO) when trying to connect**

I cant access phpMyAdmin and I dont even know what it has been changed it.
I also tried storing a backup of my bin folder but there has been no change.

I tried checking my config.inc.php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] is set to 'root'

i also tried this:

> **mountainlion:~ mountainlion$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password 'root'
> **Enter password:
>
> **/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
> error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

I would truly appreciate the assistance as I've been stuck on this for a few days now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to just reinstall it. Yes, I lost all the databases I had on it, but i had a back up of them so, everything was peachy.